# Adding view to RecyclerView from another fragment: Interface of static?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have one activity and 2 fragments that never run simultaneously, A and B. Fragment A has a RecyclerView, and from fragment B I want to add views to that ReyclerView.

I know the documentation says two fragments should never communicate directly, but I'm not sure how far that goes and if my case is really considered communication.

Should I use a static method or implement an interface in the activity?

Comment: You should communicate through the activity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is use EventBus library. I have a demo app in which you can add items to RecyclerView from anywhere within the app using EventBus. Here is the link to the repo:

https://github.com/code-crusher/android-demos/tree/master/EventBusDemo

And if you want to understand how it works you can refer to my article:

[https://medium.com/@code_crusher/eventbus-for-android](https://medium.com/@code_crusher/eventbus-for-android-4afa17863884#.cbg1u7w2j)

Hope it helps. Happy coding :)